# VS Code: error AL0445: The file is opened in another application. Close the application to be able to compile

Tags: visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, vscode-tasks, dynamics-business-central

Hy,

I can't compile in VS Code. According to the VS Code terminal output, a .rdl file is open in another application. But that is not correct, the file is not open in another application or anywhere else. I have already tried to delete the rdl.file via the explorer together with the corresponding al.file from the explorer. But every time I compile again, the deleted .rdl file reappears in my project folder, even though I clear the cache via VS Code and Explorer. If I then insert the .al file again and try to compile, the error message appears again and the package cannot be created.

Are there ways to work around this problem using configurations in launch.json or tasks.json?

I have already read questions and answers in various forums about the AL0445 error, but unfortunately none of them have been able to help me so far

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have multiple `report` objects pointing to the same layout file.

Try searching for the file name of the `.rdl` file in your workspace to determine if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling a report object in which there is a reference to an .rdl or .rdlc layout, the DataSet in the layout is updated.
If several reports all have a reference to a single layout, compilation is not processed serially, but in parallel.

Example:
A project contains Report A and Report B, each of which refers to the same layout. Report A is compiled when the project is compiled. This leads to an update in the layout. Report B is already compiled before the compilation of Report A is completed. Compiling Report B also updates the DataSet in the layout. However, this update cannot be carried out as the update by Report A has not yet been completed.

If you program in AL and have installed the AL extension from Microsoft in VS Code, you can add the following parameter to settings.json:

```
"al.compilationOptions": {
    "parallel": false
}
```

If you set the parameter "parallel" to false, serial compilation is used and the error no longer appears.